# What mean the params returned from Paperclip in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have defined my paths like this with Paperclip:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/photos/:style/:id.:extension",
:url => "/system/photos/:style/:id.:extension"
```

Now im wondering for what the params in the file url stand?

For example: `1405493881` in this url:

```
/system/photos/medium/82.png?1405493881
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last part of the url is anti caching timestamp...

if you want to disable that you can use

```
# assuming your model have something similar to the following
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => { ...yada yada styles...  },
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/photos/:style/:id.:extension",
  :url => "/system/photos/:style/:id.:extension",
  :use_timestamp => false
```

this will not create the timestamp for the url

check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802230/remove-question-mark-from-paperclip-generated-files-in-ruby-on-rails-3-2-6)

also the [source code documentation here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L55)